# How to add "+ New Object" on lookup search bar field in a Salesforce object?

Tags: salesforce, crm

I created a lookup field of Work Type object (Standard Object) in Babel Procedure (Custom Object), but on lookup search bar does not appears a "+ New Object" when I click on search field.

For example, this is the face of my Babel Procedure Object that have 2 lookup fields: Procedure and Duration (the lookup field of Work Type).

[image]

When I click on search bar field of Procedure, the "+ New Procedure" appears.

[image]

But, on Duration field, the "+ New Duration" does not appears to be pressed. I don't know why this is happens. My profile is admin, so I don't think is a permission problem.

[image]

Anyone have an idea of why this is happens with this object?

Comment: Does your current user have Create access to the Duration object?

Comment: Yes, I check the Profile and my User have access.

https://i.imgur.com/AhwKI9S.png